# How to use `apply` in Kotlin when property and function have the same variable name

Tags: kotlin

```kotlin
data class Foo(
  var aaa: String,
  var bbb: String
)
```

```kotlin
fun bar(aaa: String) {
  Foo().apply {
    aaa = aaa // this line gives error
    bbb = "bbb"
  }
}
```

IDE gives an error `Val cannot be reassigned` which suggests it's trying to reassign the function level `aaa`.

how can I correctly use `apply` here to assign value of function level variable `aaa` to Foo's property `aaa`?

---

Edit:

Correct variables in data class from `val` to `var` (my mistake)
as if they are `val` they cannot be modified in `apply`.

Comment: Even with _this.aaa = aaa_ both lines, _this.aaa = aaa_ and _bbb = "bbb"_ would still have this error, since _aaa_ and _bbb_ in _Foo_ are immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @Nikolai Shevchenko answered this can be done using `this`.

When having a szenario where `this` references multiple instances with a same variable name, you can add a [label](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/returns.html) to determine the exact target.

```kotlin
fun bar(aaa: String) {
    Foo().apply {
        this@apply.aaa = aaa    // no error
        bbb = "bbb"       // this.bbb can also be used, but is excessive here
    }
}
```

```kotlin
data class Foo1(var aaa: String, var bbb: String)
data class Foo2(var aaa: String)

fun bar(aaa: String) {
    Foo1().apply foo1@{
        Foo2().apply foo2@{
            // this.aaa references either Foo1 or Foo2, should have a label to target the correct one. When no label is given Foo2 will get the variable assignment
            this@foo1.aaa = aaa    // no error
            this@foo2.aaa = aaa    // no error
            bbb = "bbb"       // this.bbb can also be used, but is excessive here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `this` reference

```kotlin
fun bar(aaa: String) {
    Foo().apply {
        this.aaa = aaa    // no error
        bbb = "bbb"       // this.bbb can also be used, but is excessive here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct in that you can use `this.aaa`, but only as long as you're defining `aaa` using `var`, not `val` which makes it immutable. However, if all you're trying to do is to create a `Foo` instance with the passed properties, you don't have to use `apply`; all you need to do is:

```
fun bar(aaa: String) {
    Foo(
        aaa = aaa,
        bbb = "bbb"
    )
}
```

In this constructor named parameter syntax, there is no ambiguity: the first `aaa` is the parameter name and the second `aaa` is the value of the parameter that was passed to `bar`.

Comment: thanks. it makes sense. my bad i was mean to ask for the var solution. i'll update the question